# Filtering out dates returns blank array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter out any objects within the array that has a date before 01/03/2020. However when I run the code below no objects are returned in the `console.log`, I would expect this  `{'date': '01/01/2019'}` to be there.

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [
      {'date': '01/01/2019'},
      {'date': '01/01/2021'},
      {'date': '01/01/2022'},
      {'date': '01/01/2023'},
      {'date': '01/01/2024'}
]
    
console.log(arrayOfObjects.filter(object => {return object['date'] > '01/03/2020'}))
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Comment: you are comparing strings, not dates...

Comment: >.< Whooopps!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `new Date()` to convert the `string` values to `Date` type.

This should work:

```js
const data = [
  {'date': '01/01/2019'},
  {'date': '01/01/2021'},
  {'date': '01/01/2022'},
  {'date': '01/01/2023'},
  {'date': '01/01/2024'}
];

const result = data.filter(e => new Date(e.date) > new Date('01/03/2020'));

console.log(result);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Ahh I see where I have gone wrong now, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

To compare dates you will need to wrap the string date values inside `new Date()` in order to create a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object like:

```js
let arr = [
  {'date': '01/01/2019'},
  {'date': '01/01/2021'},
  {'date': '01/01/2022'},
  {'date': '01/01/2023'},
  {'date': '01/01/2024'}
];

const result = arr.filter(({date}) => new Date(date) > new Date('01/03/2020'));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Right now it just comparing string values which is returning all false. Hence, you are getting an empty array.

```js
console.log('01/01/2019' > '01/03/2020')
console.log('01/01/2021' > '01/03/2020')
console.log('01/01/2022' > '01/03/2020')
console.log('01/01/2023' > '01/03/2020')
console.log('01/01/2024' > '01/03/2020')
```

But if you wrap it in Date object, you get only one as false:

```js
console.log( new Date('01/01/2019') > new Date('01/03/2020') )
console.log( new Date('01/01/2021') > new Date('01/03/2020') )
console.log( new Date('01/01/2022') > new Date('01/03/2020') )
console.log( new Date('01/01/2023') > new Date('01/03/2020') )
console.log( new Date('01/01/2024') > new Date('01/03/2020') )
```